# How do you define an affine transformation that is translated by itself?

Tags: graphics

This one should be simple, but I can't figure it out. I would like to define a transformation (function) such that $r$ maps to $m.r + r$

The help file on AffineTransformation says that

```
AffineTransformation[{m,v}]
```

maps $r$ to $m.r + v$

so for example

```
tt = AffineTransform[{d*IdentityMatrix[2], {a, b}}]
tt[{x,y}]
{a+dx,b+dy}
```

But how would I define a transformation such that it would return

```
tt[{x,y}]
{x+dx,y+dy}
```

for any ${x,y}$?

And that it could be applied to graphics objects, e.g,

```
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[], tt[d]]
```

where I have added a function argument `d` which is a parameter of the transformation function.

Answer (score 3):

**Summary**

There are several things going on here:

1. The `a` and `b` in the expression are fixed parameters and don't substitute for your inputs. Try a pure function or a standard function using `SetDelayed` as shown below.
2. What you are trying to create is not an `AffineTransformation`.
3. It's not immediately obvious how to pass the coordinates back into the transformation function (to this economist, it's not even clear if this works geometrically).

---

Part of the answer (item 1) lies in the difference between a *function* and a `TransformationFunction`. What you want is to substitute `a` and `b` for whatever values you pass it. Try this instead:

```
ttt[{a_, b_}] := 
 AffineTransform[{d*IdentityMatrix[2], {a, b}}][{a, b}]

ttt[{x, y}]
(* {x + d x, y + d y} *)
```

What's going on here? Looking at the output of your original `tt` function, reveals a [`TransformationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TransformationFunction.html), which defines a function much like a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) that can then be applied to some data.

```
tt
(*TransformationFunction[{{d, 0, a}, {0, d, b}, {0, 0, 1}}]*)
TransformationFunction[{{d, 0, a}, {0, d, b}, {0, 0, 1}}][{p,q}]
(* {a + d p, b + d q} *)
```

But the `a` and `b` are fixed parameters, not variables that are substituted by the data passed to the function. That's why you need to do it as per the `ttt` function above, using [`SetDelayed` (`:=`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html).

An alternative way to do what you want would be to define your function as a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html). Notice the ampersand and the [`Slot` (`#`) notation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html).

```
ttpure = AffineTransform[{d*IdentityMatrix[2], {#1, #2}}][{#1, #2}] &
```

But watch out, the syntax of the expected input is a bit different now - it expects two arguments, not inside curly braces (`List` expression):

```
ttpure[x, y]
(* {x + d x, y + d y} *)
```

If you have a pair of variables inside a list, then you need to use `Apply` (`@@`).

```
ttpure @@ {x, y}
(* {x + d x, y + d y} *)
```

Alternatively, you can restore the behaviour of `ttt` in taking a two-element list as the input by having a single `Slot` argument and accessing its `Part`s like this:

```
ttp2 = AffineTransform[{d*
  IdentityMatrix[2], {#[[1]], #[[2]]}}][{#[[1]], #[[2]]}] &
```

Personally I find the `#[[]]` notation to be quite ugly, but it works as required as long as you actually pass an argument that is a list with at least two elements:

```
ttp2[{x, y}]
(* {x + d x, y + d y} *)

ttp2[{x}]
```

> Part::partw: Part 2 of {x} does not exist. >>
>   Part::partw: Part 2 of {x} does not exist. >>

```
(* {x + d x, {x}[[2]] + d {x}[[2]]} *)

ttp2[{x, y, z}]
(* {x + d x, y + d y} *)
```

**Edit in response to comment**

To actually make this work on a graphic, you need everything to be numeric. Notice I've added a third argument (`#3`) here.

```
ttpure = AffineTransform[{#3*IdentityMatrix[2], {#1, #2}}][{#1, #2}] &

Framed@Graphics[GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[], 
 ttpure[0.3, 0.6, 0.2]], PlotRange -> 1]
```

[image]

However, this isn't quite what you want, since the actual coordinates aren't passed into the `TransformationFunction`, only the parameters you pass. (This will have to wait for a later update.)

Comment: Fantastic! This works exactly. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand quite correctly. Does this mean ttt is not a TransformationFunction? I.e, it doesn't seem like I can use it to transform a graphics object (e.g. a Rectangle) using GeometricTransformation. I.e. `Graphics[GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[], ttt]]`

Comment: You are welcome @ShaunH - have a look at my edit. It might be helpful. And by the way, welcome to Mathematica.SE!

Comment: `ttt` is a function that applies a  `TransformationFunction` to the input, rather than just defining the function. Hopefully my addition, especially `ttpure` clarifies the difference. For the case you mention in comments, try `ttpure`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Verbeia, but I don't quite understand why you would have to specify the coordinates `x` and `y`. Is there a way to make `d` the (only) argument, so for example, `Framed@Graphics[GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[], 
 ttpure[0.2]]` where the 0.2 is the chosen `d`?

Comment: @ShaunH - those aren't coordinates: from the documents: "`AffineTransform[{m,v}]` gives an affine transform that maps $r$ to $m.r+v$." Your `x` and `y` are the elements of $v$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4727/discussion-between-shaunh-and-verbeia)